# I am using Swift-SRWebClient to upload multiple images in single post but i am not able to do so with swift 2.2? using REST API

Tags: swift

Here is my code :

```
SRWebClient.POST("http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/upload/upload.php").data(messageData, fieldName:"photo", data: ["CreatedBy":"4","Name": "Test", "Description" :"Test","CategoryId": "0", "SendToSupplier":"0","DeliveryDate":"25/10/2016","FileExtension":"png"])
        .send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
            // process success response
            },failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                // process failure response
        })
```

This method gives me the error

> Cannot invoke with an argument list of type .....

Comment: Can you help me out to call this method using SRWebClient.POST

Comment: SRWebClient.POST("YOUR URL/M/API").data(YorARRAYOFIMAGEDATA, fieldName:"photo", data: ["CreatedBy":"4","Name": "Test", "Description" :"Test","CategoryId": "0", "SendToSupplier":"0","DeliveryDate":"25/10/2016","FileExtension":"png"])
            .send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
                print("Success")
                self.navigationController?.popFadeToRootViewController()
                },failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                    print("failure")
            })

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Instead, [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SRWebClient.POST("YOUR URL/M/API").data(YorARRAYOFIMAGEDATA,
                                        fieldName:"photo",
                                        data: [
                                            "CreatedBy":"4",
                                            "Name": "Test",
                                            "Description" :"Test",
                                            "CategoryId": "0",
                                            "Parameters":"0",
                                            "DeliveryDate":"25/10/2016",
                                            "FileExtens‌​ion":"png"
    ])
    .send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
        print("Success")
        self.navigationController?.popFadeToRootViewController()
    }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
        print("failure")
    }
)
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question? Or were you trying to update your question?